# How to check that node.js script is running on terminal or web?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, terminal

The first, I've never used node.js before, anyway I know that it able to run natively on a terminal. If I build some application which can also run on terminal and web browser, how can I check that now node.js is run on terminal or web browser?

Comment: what's your end game?

Comment: @DanielA.White sorry, what do you mean by "end game"?

Answer (score 1):

It's javascript, not node.js which is run in terminal (node.js) or in the browser.

In order to check if your code is executed in node or in browser you can check if something specific to environment is defined, like `window` (browser) or `global` (node), but it's not 100% reliable, because another code can define these objects.

I would suggest using something like `detect-node` https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-node